# jQuery UI - bounce - div jumping from left to right

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a problem with my site, where I am using jQuery with jQuery UI on it, to create a bounce effect on the login box.

However, I have a problem with the div with the login boxes in, as it bounces on the left side of the screen, when it should bounce in the middle, where it also jumps in when it is done bouncing.

I have created a JSFiddle to demonstrate it:
http://jsfiddle.net/prooi/GqyfX/

If you could take a look, and give me some idea of why it is behaving like that, it would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think about jquery ui bounce effect? http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/

Comment: @MateuszRogulski I didnt really understand what you meant to say. Can you try again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert another div in container and apply the jquery code on that i.e.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="nested"> 
     <!-- Your Existing Html Markup -->
  </div>
</div>
```

and apply the jquery code on **nested** div i.e

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nested").effect('bounce', 250);
});
```

The problem will get resolved :)

Comment: Thanks! That was the easiest way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in your javascript :

```
    $('#container').css('margin-left', $('#container').width()- $('#container').width()/2);
```

And remove the `left:auto;` and the `margin:auto;` in the css of `#container`

here's the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/GqyfX/2/

In the fiddle it's not so great because of the size of the example, but try it in your website

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it is however a bit more work to do than just inserting another div to do the job.